# Using multiple private repos in same vc location

Tags: composer-php, satis

To put it simpley the best I can: we have a private VC repo with a list of composer packages we use internally -- [our-bitbucket.com]/comp/

Each package has it's own repo. Each package is namespaced under [orgname]/ within their `composer.json` configuration.

What I'm trying to do is clean up this mess:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "ssh://git@our-bitbucket.com/comp/package1",
      "options": {
        "ssh2": {
          "username": "git",
          "pubkey_file": ".ssh/pub-key",
          "privkey_file": ".ssh/priv-key"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "ssh://git@our-bitbucket.com/comp/package2",
      "options": {
        "ssh2": {
          "username": "git",
          "pubkey_file": ".ssh/pub-key",
          "privkey_file": ".ssh/priv-key"
        }
      }
    },
// [... a dozen more times ...]
],
```

Is there any better and simpler way manage this? This repo list is getting pretty large. We need to clean it up. I don't suppose there's some way to add a global options for the keys? By host?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I found that assists in cleaning up this file: storing credentials in `.ssh/config`, modifying the URLs to match the config setting. e.g.

`.ssh/config:`

```
Host our-bitbucket.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/priv-key
# ----------------------------
```

`satis.json`

```
  "repositories": [
    {"type": "vcs", "url": "ssh://git@our-bitbucket.com/comp/package2"},
    //[... dozen more lines ...]
   ]
```

It at least saves us from having to define a priv/pub key for each and every repo definition.